# React using state array without mutation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Can the below code be refactored so as to not mutate the state array. Basically, I want that as I navigate the app back and forth via props.history.push, it should not recreate the array, as I my aim is to preserve the selected option.

```
const [options1, setOptions1] = useState([
    {value: 'ABC', text: 'ABC', id: 1},
    {value: 'DEF', text: 'DEF', id: 2}
]);
const [options2, setOptions2] = useState([
    {value: 'ABC', text: 'ABC', id: 1},
    {value: 'DEF', text: 'DEF', id: 2},
    {value: 'XYZ', text: 'XYZ', id: 3}
]);

let finalOpts = options1; // Is there a better way to do this ?
if (someConditionIsTrue) {
    finalOpts = options2;
}

const [selectedOpt, setSelectedOpt] = useState(finalOpts[0]);

<MyList
    id="myDD"
    selectedOpt={selectedOpt}
    options={finalOpts}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use useMemo to precalculate the values if your UI logic depends on some conditional.
This alone will not preserve the selectedState if the component is unmounted.
In order to preserve the selected state even after the component has been unmounted, you will have to store the selection in some kind of global state.

```
const options = useMemo(() => {
  if(someConditionIsTrue) {
    return [
    {value: 'ABC', text: 'ABC', id: 1},
    {value: 'DEF', text: 'DEF', id: 2}
    ];
  }
  return [
    {value: 'ABC', text: 'ABC', id: 1},
    {value: 'DEF', text: 'DEF', id: 2},
    {value: 'XYZ', text: 'XYZ', id: 3}
]
}, [someConditionIsTrue]);

const [selectedItem, setSelectedItem] = useState();



return (<MyList
    id="myDD"
    selectedOpt={selectedItem || options[0]}
        onSelectionChanged={setSelectedItem}
    options={options}
/>)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot...This seems close to what I was looking for...just one question...actually out of the 3 options, 2 are same and only for the condition, we add 1 more option....so i was thinking to push XYZ without mutation

Comment: you can simply spread the original array and add the new element at the end, this way you will create a new Array. like so [...option1, {value: 'XYZ', id: 3}]

Comment: Hmm not sure if I option1 would be a direct asignment like {value: 'ABC', text: 'ABC', id: 1},
    {value: 'DEF', text: 'DEF', id: 2} and then I need to use the spread operator on that to add in XYZ ?

Comment: option1 would be a const inside the useMemo